# Combine column types defined in dcolumn with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, dcolumn

I'm looking for a way to define a column type which "mixes" the 'D' column defined in the `dcolumn` package and the 'X' column defined by the `tabularx` package. In other words, I want a column type that aligns cell contents by the decimal point *and* can be stretched to fit the table width I specify. Of course, it does *not* necessarily have to mix `dcolumn` and `tabularx`. Any thoughts?

Here's some code to make clear what I'm trying to achieve. The first table uses column type D from the `dcolumn` package, inside a tabular environment. How do I get the table to stretch to the width I specify?[image: table 1]

The second table uses column `X` from `tabularx` package. The table spreads the way I want, but how do I get cells aligned by the decimal point?[image: table 2]

The third table tries to combine the two. The result is obviously not what I want (although it's exactly what I'd expect).[image: table 3]

```
% preamble
\usepackage{array}       
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}    
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

% table using D from dcolumn package
\begin{table}

  \centering
  \caption{table using dcolumn}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

  \toprule
            &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{col A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col C} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
  \midrule  
       North &      2,228   &   0.300 &  10.6 \\    
       South &        689.2 &   0.8   &   2.6 \\
  \bottomrule

  \end{tabular}     
\end{table}


% table using X from tabularx
\begin{table}

  \centering
  \caption{table using tabularx}

  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{X}}

  \toprule

            &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{col A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col C} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}

  \midrule  
       North &      2,228   &   0.300 &  10.6 \\    
       South &        689.2 &   0.8   &   2.6 \\     
  \bottomrule

  \end{tabularx}    
\end{table}

% table using D inside tabularx
\begin{table}

  \centering
  \caption{table using dcolumn inside tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

  \toprule
            &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{col A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{col C} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
  \midrule  
       North &      2,228   &   0.300 &  10.6 \\    
       South &        689.2 &   0.8   &   2.6 \\
  \bottomrule

  \end{tabularx}    
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Never tried it before but....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}       
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}    
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

% table using D from dcolumn package
\begin{table}

  \centering
  \caption{table using dcolumn}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{3}{d{-2}}}

  \toprule
            &  \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering col A} &
 \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering col B} &
 \multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering col C} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
  \midrule  
       North &      2,228   &   0.300 &  10.6 \\    
       South &        689.2 &   0.8   &   2.6 \\
  \bottomrule

  \end{tabularx}     
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew that if anyone could do it, you would be the one! :-)

Comment: @David So the trick here is to ensure you have at least (and perhaps at most) one \multicolumn{}{X}{}, right?

Comment: @djas seems so:-)

Answer (score 6):

I don't see how one might combine the decimal-aligning capabilities of the `dcolumn` package with the width-setting capabilities of the `tabularx` package. (However, David Carlisle might just decide to show how this might be done after all. *Update*: Sure enough, he did!)

You could, though, use the `tabular*` environment (part of core-LaTeX, no extra package required) along with the `dcolumn` package. Unlike the `tabular` environment, which takes one argument (the set of column specifications), `tabular*` takes two arguments: the overall width, and the set of column specifications. The big difference between `tabular*` and `tabularx` is that whereas the latter works by expanding by column widths suitably, the former works by adjusting the amount of intercolumn whitespace.

The "trick", such as it is, is to use the construct `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to *expand the intercolumn white space* so that the `tabular*` environment takes up the full width specified in the environment's first argument. In the example below, which is largely adapted from your first example, columns 2, 3, and 4 all have the same widths because of the dcolumn specifier `d{6.3}`; this can be verified by comparing the lengths of the three `\cmidrule`s. (Aside: because the table features plenty of intercolumn whitespace, it's not necessary to trim the `\cmidrule`s to assure some separation between them.) The columns are separated by equal amounts of intercolumn whitespace, courtesy of the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive.

I hope this is, more or less, what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\noindent
The width of the text block is indicated by this horizontal rule:
\hrule

\begin{table}[h] % I'm the "h" location specifier just to assure that the table is typeset after the \hrule...
\caption{Table using dcolumn and tabular*}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{3}{d{6.3}}}
\toprule
&  \mc{col A} & \mc{col B} & \mc{col C} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{3-3} \cmidrule{4-4}
\midrule  
North &      2,228   &   0.300 &  10.6 \\    
South &        689.2 &   0.8   &   2.6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}     
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your output looks pretty much what I had in mind, yes. However, `tabularx` and `tabular*`do give different results in general. Do you think in this particular case, where column type is `d` this won't happen? I remember not going with `tabular*`because of some examples I saw.

Comment: @djas - I'm pretty sure that it's helpful, in the `tabular*` example, to specify the same column parameters (d{6.3}) for all three numerical columns. Comparing the outputs of the examples David and I came up with, what strikes me is that there's a lot of empty whitespace to the right of the righthand-most column when using the `tabularx` method, whereas the issue isn't as pronounced when using the `tabular*` method. The fact that the three intercolumn whitespaces are the same under the `tabular*` method, whereas that's not the case under the `tabularx` method, may also be worth contemplating.