# Formatting a table in a article

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

I'm new on latex and it is complicated to do some things. I'm using a documentclass article and I have the problem in the figure.
[image]

The table is too long and the last column doesn't appear, it is in the right side of the article. I used this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{lccr}
\toprule
     \textit{Patient category} & \textit{Shapiro-Wilk Test} &  \textit{D’Agostino’s $K^2$ Test} & \textit{Anderson-Darling Test}\\
     \midrule 
    \textbf{HC}        & 0.993 & 0.976 & 0.145\\
    \textbf{PD ICD}    & 0.286 & 0.040 & 0.426\\
    \textbf{PD No ICD} & 0.618 & 0.605 & 0.256\\
    \bottomrule
\label{tab:t}
\end{tabular}
```

How can I solve it?

This is the final code (solved), but doesn't appear the caption. How want to add just it on the top of the table. Also the text after the table is not aligned with the text below the table. Finally, when I compile it return different warning and errors: undefined control sequence on  \midskip... ; \caption outside float and Overfull hbox in \noindent

```
\noindent
    \midskip\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}%
        L{0.86} C{0.95}C{1.2}C{0.99}@{}} % Note: 0.86+0.95+1.2+0.99=4.0=# of X-type cols.
    \toprule
    \mycell{} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Test}}\\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
    Patient Category & Shapiro-Wilk & D'Agostino's $K^2$ & Anderson-Darling\\
    \midrule 
        HC        & 0.993 & 0.976 & 0.145\\
        PD ICD    & 0.286 & 0.040 & 0.426\\
        PD~No~ICD & 0.618 & 0.605 & 0.256\\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Are shown the p-values for the different tests}
    \label{table:1}
    \end{tabularx}

    exampleeeeasdasd
```

I add:

result:

[image]

What i want:

```
0.976
0.040**
0.605
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., does it employ a two-column layout? How wide are the columns? Which font packages, if any, does the document load? What's the main font size?

Comment: I use \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}, so the article is divived in 2 columns

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: You can only use the `\caption` command inside of a `table` (or `figure`) environment. Thus, remove the `\noindent`, replace it with `\begin{table}` and add an `\end{table}` right after `\end{tabularx}`. And move the `\caption` command outside of `tabularx` but inside of `table`.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis it works !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? (You didn't provide much information, forcing me to make quite a few assumptions which may not be correct.) The proposed solution employs a `tabularx` environments and that line breaks occur in all four columns of the header row.

[image]

Observe that I've also removed the *italics* from the header row and the **bold-facing** from the header column -- it shouldn't be necessary to use such highlighting for a table that's this small and compact. A simple, clear layout should suffice to guide your readers' eyes.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,booktabs,sectsty}
\paragraphfont{\mdseries\itshape}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\smash{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\paragraph{Anderson-Darling Test.} The results are summed up in the following table.

\smallskip\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}%
    L{0.86} C{0.95}C{1.2}C{0.99}@{}} % Note: 0.86+0.95+1.2+0.99=4.0=# of X-type cols.
\toprule
\mycell{Patient category} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Test}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& Shapiro-Wilk & D'Agostino's $K^2$ & Anderson-Darling\\
\midrule 
    HC        & 0.993 & 0.976 & 0.145\\
    PD ICD    & 0.286 & 0.040 & 0.426\\
    PD~No~ICD & 0.618 & 0.605 & 0.256\\
\bottomrule
\label{tab:t}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a vertical at 0,286

Comment: @jsbibra - I guess there is. Is it distracting?

Comment: nope thought my eyes were giving way

Comment: @jsbibra - I've gone ahead and updated the screenshot. Gotta give your eyes some rest. :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Is there a way to have Patient category aligned with the name of the tests ? So more down. And also how can i create a empty space between the table and the text ? (not the description, but the paragraph above)

Comment: @Will - To move the string "Patient category" down to the line of the subheader cells, just (a) delete `\mycell{Patient category}`  and (b) insert `Patient category` (note: no `\mycell` wrapper needed) immediately before `& Shapiro-Wilk`. To increase the vertical separation, just replace `\smallskip` with either `\medskip` or `\bigskip`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. How can i add the caption ? because the first part is the paragraph. I want to add something like: \caption{Are shown the p-values for the different tests.}. But this doen't appear in the pdf

Comment: @Will -  Is there something stopping you from encasing the tabular-related material (including the `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` directive) in a `table` environment and inserting a suitable `\caption` statement? (My mind-reading skills are sadly -- but probably not surprisingly -- non-existent. The code you posted contained no `table` and `\caption` material, and the accompanying screenshot contained but the barest hint of such material. Hence I didn't try to fathom what you were trying to do in that regard.)

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @Will - (a) The macro's name is `\medskip`, not `\midskip`. (b) The `\caption` and `\label` statements must be placed *outside* the `tabularx` environment. (c) It appears that you want the tabular material right where it is. Hence, you should *not* use a `table` environment. Instead, load the `caption` package (in the preamble) via `\usepackage{caption}`, delete `caption{Are shown the p-values for the different tests}`, and insert `\captionof{table}{$p$-values for various tests}` *before* the `tabularx` env.

Comment: @Mico last things. I added this line: \multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\ after the \bottomrule. If a put & **0.040 (center of the table) it does not aligned with the others. How can i solve it ?

Comment: @Will - Please clarify what `If a put & **0.040 (center of the table) it does not aligned with the others` might mean.

Comment: @Mico I edited again the question

Comment: @Will - AFAICT, `\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}` is completely separate and independent from the other parts. Is this correct? Second, you're not writing `**0.040` but `0.040**`, right? Finally, are you asking how to align numbers on their decimal markers instead of simply centering them in a column?

Comment: How can i center in a column the number ?

Comment: @Will - the entries in the three data columns *are* centered in my answer.

Comment: @Mico - Yes, infact when i put 0.040**, it center all the value with the **. So it is not aligned respect to the first decimal.

Comment: @Will -3 hours ago, I asked you whether the numbers should be centered or aligned on the decimal markers. To this, you replied 2 hours ago with the question "How can I center ... the number?" But now your most recent comment seems to want alignment on the decimal markers. Are we really decided that we want to align the numbers on their decimal markers? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I want  to align the numbers on their decimal markers

Comment: @Will - Please study the postings [Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2746/5001) and [Combine column types defined in dcolumn with tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141671/5001).

Comment: @Mico - Ok thanks !!! If you have a good pdf or other things of latex please send me. Final things. Do you know what is the * in \begin{figure*} ?? What is the difference from \begin{figure}

Comment: @Will - In a two-column document, `figure` and `table` environments span a single column, whereas `figure*` and `table*` documents span both columns. You should use the latter if (and only if) you need to display graphics or tables that cannot fit in a single column.

Comment: @Mico I have only one problem. If I put an image and it is doesn't not enter In the page; latex put the text, the title of the table (table 1: example), the image and then the table!!! So the caption is not in the top of the table. They are separated, why ?

Comment: @Will - I'm afraid you haven't provided nearly enough information to allow a confident diagnosis, let alone a workable solution. For example, what does "if I put an image" entail? Is its width single-column or double-column? Please post a *new" query. Doing so will assure that it will be seen by many more people than just me.

Comment: @Mico I can't modify the question again, how can I contact you in private ?

Comment: @Will - No, please post a *new query".

Comment: @Mico I made a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542400/214295

Comment: @Mico can you help me with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542676/214295 thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach using `makecell` and `tabular*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text using \lispum. remove in actual document.
\usepackage{booktabs} % for horizontal lines with imptoved spacing
\usepackage{makecell} % for the \thead command
\usepackage{caption} % for improved spacing around captions
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Are shown the p-values for the different tests}  \label{table:1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l ccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \thead[l]{Patient\\ Category} 
      & \thead{Shapiro-\\Wilk Test} 
        & \thead{D'Agostino's\\ $K^2$ Test} 
          & \thead{Anderson-\\Darling Test}\\
    \midrule 
        HC        & 0.993 & 0.976 & 0.145\\
        PD ICD    & 0.286 & 0.040 & 0.426\\
        PD~No~ICD & 0.618 & 0.605 & 0.256\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, using tabular*. I also took the liberty to add the tabular inside a table-environment and add a caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, font=raggedright, font=it,labelfont=bf, skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\theadl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\small\itshape\begin{tabular}{l} #1\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\theadc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\itshape\begin{tabular}{c} #1\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\theadr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{\small\itshape\begin{tabular}{r}#1\end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Result of three tests types\label{tab:t}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}>{\itshape}wl{0.225\linewidth}wc{0.225\linewidth}wc{0.225\linewidth}wr{0.225\linewidth}}
\toprule
\theadl{Patient\\category} & \theadc{Shapiro \\Wilk} &  \theadc{D’Agostino’s\\$K^2$} & \theadr{Anderson-\\Darling}\\
\midrule 
HC              & 0.993 & 0.976 & 0.145\\
PD ICD       & 0.286 & 0.040 & 0.426\\
PD No ICD & 0.618 & 0.605 & 0.256\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```