# \captionof problem

Tags: tables, floats, captions, tabularx

using this code I have a problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\paragraphfont{\mdseries\itshape}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2019} % requires 'acl2019.sty'
%%%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{acl2019.bib}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=small,textfont={it,small},
            justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\smash{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package last

\aclfinalcopy % requires 'acl2019.sty'

\begin{document}
\subsection{Data distributions}
you can see the figure \ref{fig:distribution} and figure \ref{fig:density}.
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/HC_Distribution.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:distribution}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/HC_Density.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:density}
\end{figure}
The results are summed up in the following table \ref{table:1}.
\medskip\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\captionof{table}{$p$-values for various tests} \label{table:1}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}%
    L{0.86} C{0.95}C{1.2}C{0.99}@{}} % Note: 0.86+0.95+1.2+0.99=4.0=# of X-type cols.
\toprule
\mycell{} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
Patient Category & Shapiro-Wilk & D'Agostino's $K^2$ & Anderson-Darling\\
\midrule 
    HC        & 0.315 & 0.104 & (0.334)\\
    PD ICD    & 0.694 & 0.180 & (0.256)\\
    PD~No~ICD & 0.251 & 0.453 & (0.380)\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parenthesis}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\end{tabularx}
Then \dots
\end{document}
```

The problem is that latex print first caption of the table, then the two figures and last the table. So the caption is separate from the table.
The problem is in the figures attached:

[image]

At this point the page ended and then:

[image]

Comment: Enclose the tabularx and caption-of in a minipage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the table and the `\caption-of` command in a `minipage`- or a `table`-environment. I have reduced your code to an (M)WE.

You may also use a table-environment, as demonstrated in example 2 below:

In addition, I suggest that you use [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) for references. 
You then just write `\cref{<label>}` instead of `figure~ref{<label>}` etc. to make a reference. In addition, [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) has lot of other possibilities for formatting and concatenation *etc*., which will help you produce a nice and consistent document. Much more convenient.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt,a4paper, demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,booktabs,sectsty}
\usepackage[labelfont=small,textfont={it,small},justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\smash{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Data distributions}
you can see the \cref{fig:distribution} and \cref{fig:density}.
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/HC_Distribution.png}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:distribution}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/HC_Density.png}
  \begin{center}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:density}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

The results are summed up in the following \cref{table:1}.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\medskip\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\captionof{table}{$p$-values for various tests}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}%
    L{0.86} C{0.95}C{1.2}C{0.99}@{}} % Note: 0.86+0.95+1.2+0.99=4.0=# of X-type cols.
\toprule
\mycell{} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
Patient Category & Shapiro-Wilk & D'Agostino's $K^2$ & Anderson-Darling\\
\midrule 
    HC        & 0.315 & 0.104 & (0.334)\\
    PD ICD    & 0.694 & 0.180 & (0.256)\\
    PD~No~ICD & 0.251 & 0.453 & (0.380)\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parenthesis}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\label{table:1}
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - using the table-environment**

I have not repeated all code, only the table environment.

```
\begin{table}[!hb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{$p$-values for various tests}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}%
    L{0.86} C{0.95}C{1.2}C{0.99}@{}} % Note: 0.86+0.95+1.2+0.99=4.0=# of X-type cols.
\toprule
\mycell{} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
Patient Category & Shapiro-Wilk & D'Agostino's $K^2$ & Anderson-Darling\\
\midrule 
    HC        & 0.315 & 0.104 & (0.334)\\
    PD ICD    & 0.694 & 0.180 & (0.256)\\
    PD~No~ICD & 0.251 & 0.453 & (0.380)\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parenthesis}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.01}\\
\label{table:1}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I used the first solution. Why cleveref is better ?

Comment: You just write `\cref{<label>}` instead of `figure~ref{<label>}` . In addition, cleverer has  to lot of possibilities for formatting and concatenation etc. Have a look at the description in the manual. It is called `clever` for a good reason.

Comment: Ok thanks, I saw some things, but I however use for e.g. \cref{eq:1} and not \cref{1}. Where 1 is the label for a equation