# Shift \titlegraphic logo upwards in beamer title frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, presentations

How can I up the image inside \titlegraphic vertically ???
this is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Madrid}      % Antibes, Dresden
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\usefonttheme{default}  % serif
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % dynamic
%\useoutertheme{infolines} 
%\useinnertheme{rounded}
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\title{TITLE}
\subtitle{Project}
\author[A \& B]{A \& B 
    \\\texttt{\footnotesize name@ff.com} 
    \\\texttt{\footnotesize name@ff.com}
    \\~\\
    \\\small Professor: xx
    \\\small Supervised by: ttt}

\date[\today]{\today}
\institute[]{University}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image.png}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\end{frame}

\section{ex1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\end{frame}

\section{ex2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the result (the square is the o [image]

The

Comment: please include code which can be compiled

Comment: @jsbibra I added the all code.

Comment: Despite multiple tries your code does not compille, please verify it. Also, we do not have your image so that won't work eitherway. If you want to rotate the image just do `\includegraphics[angle=<something in degrees>]{image}`

Comment: @BambOo I want the image up not rotate

Comment: I misunderstood that I thought you meant to rotate it upwards, my bad.  Then you could do something like `\titlegraphic{\vspace{-<shift>}\hfill\raisebox{<shift>}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a.png}}}` (very minimal solution)

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locally correct the vertical position of the image inserted via `\titlegraphic`, i.e. without redefining the `titlepage`, you can use

```
\titlegraphic{\vspace{-<shift>}\raisebox{<shift>}{\includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}}}
```

If you only use `\raisebox`, the image will be shifted but so will be the title. The `\vspace` makes the shift transparent to other items of the `titlepage`.